# Getting object from field form

Tags: java, spring-mvc, velocity

Problem: getting an object from a  field as a parameter.

Code:
Entity User with fields:

```
Long id;
String name;
Office office;
```

Entity office with fields:

```
Long id;
String name;
```

newuser.vm

```
<title>NEW USER</title>
<body>
<form method="post" action="/save" property="user">  
    Name:
    <input type="text" name="name" path="name"/>    <br>

    Office:
    <select name="office" path="office">
        #foreach($office in $offices)
            <option value="$office">$office.name</option>
        #end
    </select>    <br>
    <input type="submit" value="SAVE"/>
</form>
</body>
```

And the Controller

```
@Controller
public class ViewController {

    @Autowired
    private UserService userService;
    @Autowired
    private OfficeService officeService;

@RequestMapping(value = "/newuser", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public ModelAndView newuser(){

        return new ModelAndView("fragments/newuser.vm","command",new User());
    }
@RequestMapping(value = "/save", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public ModelAndView save(@ModelAttribute("user") User user){

        userService.create(user);
        return new ModelAndView("redirect:/list");
    }
//Model Attributes
    @ModelAttribute
    public void userTypesList(Model model){
        model.addAttribute("types", userService.getPositions());
    }
    @ModelAttribute
    public void officesList(Model model){
        model.addAttribute("offices", officeService.getAll();
}
```

So in the result of submition I have to get the new User with an Office as one of its fields. But the  `<option value="$office">$office.name</option>` returns a string representation of the object but not the object itself i guess. So i need to find a way to correctly get that to the /save controller.
Ofcourse I can get field by field data from the form and create a new user manualy getting the office.id from the form and than sending another request to sql to get the officeById(id), but that seems to be the bad way of coding.
Anyone can help?

Comment: this is not an answer but a question, why you're still using forms? :o means are you serious?

Comment: I`m just studding, so I`m using stuff I can get some information about. If you have any better solutions feel fre to tell me, I will gladly look in the other stuff if it will help me code better/easier/faster.

Comment: Instead of studying already hated way, you can learn firstly simple ajax calls, don't tight couple your back-end and front end with this approach.
You are already in learning phase so I would suggest start with Spring MVC and Angular 2. for basic knowledge start with simple jQuery ajax calls send and retrive data through ajax then once you get to know life cycle and start getting familiar with this approach just jump to Angular2 as you are already learning Spring MVC. Good Luck :)

Comment: Just tried some "simple ajax calls', yes it works, but i`m not happy writing this way so far. Thinking of trying Vaadin for my CRUD. Still no-one to help me out on the Question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you need is:

```
<option value="$office.id">$office.name</option>
```

That's what id fields are for. Only the office id get transmitted back when the form is submitted, and that's all you need to populate the join towards the office table while creating your new user.

To have `$office` display the string representation of the whole object (that is, its `toString()` method) is the expected behavior.

Comment: So you think I should get office.id back from the form? But the User object`s field is Office office. Let me have a try.

Comment: It didn`t work, I get HTTP 400 Exception in my browser. I also found out that if I disable the office selector in the form I can pass the data to the controller, but I get the fields wierdly filled.

Comment: Sorry I did not put all of the code of the classes here to make it simplier to see, but in reality i`ve got a bit more fields in the objects: id=null, type={UserType@11601}"MANAGER", email="123", password="123", name="123", tel="123", regDate=null, lastActive=null, office=null.                        So I see that the text fields are ok and the userType is ok as it is an ENUM, but the regDate is null! Where it has to be the current Date as mentioned by the constructor of the User class. Any Ideas?

Comment: Or I should simly get the form results as List <String> and parse it in correspondence to the apropriate fiels of the User class and do getOfficeById(Long.pareLong(id)) from SQL?

Comment: In a form, a <select> field is really a key/value construct, the key being the option's `value` attribute. So there is really only *one* alternative, it's to put the id as the options' values, as I suggested. If there's a problem thereafter, it's in the way you configure your fields on the server side.

Comment: Thank you Claude, I guess I'll have to add another entity to the project which will contain the office id instead of object office.